# android - передача данных из action.SEND в запущенную активность

Tags: android, android-intent, action

Приложение обменивается данными с компом по сокетам. Активность выводит результат. Есть другая активность, которая принимает интент action.SEND, и она должна как то прокинуть данные из этого интента в уже запущенный экземпляр приложения(в activivty или презентер), чтобы отправить их на комп. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Возможно интент стоит принимать в той же активити, где данные из него и нужны? В таком случае, если оно запущено, то будет `onNewIntent` вызвано, иначе - просто в `onCreate` из интента данные достать можно.

Comment: А какой lanchmode тогда должен быть у activity?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то `singleInstance`

Comment: Перечитал [доку](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) на предмет ланчМодов. Наверное вам, всё же, `singleTop` лучше использовать. С другой стороны, словив интент в любой другой активити вы собственно можете запустить уже имеющуюся активити для вызова `onNewIntent` метода оной. Флаг во всех случаях подойдёт `singleTop`

Comment: С singleInstance работает.. singletop - срабатывает только onResume. А вообще мне не понятно, почему я не могу из другой активности открыть запущенную mainactivity и там прочитать интент? Я пробовал все флаги для интента.

Comment: Ещё момент. Тк это mainactivity, то action и gategory должны быть Main и Launher. А так получается, что они меняются

Comment: Странно, что не работает... По доке - должно вроде. Возможно создаётся другой экземпляр активити и интент приходит в `onCreate`. Вы точно можете открыть имеющуюся активити с вызовом `onNewIntent` и чтением там данных. Хоть напрямую, хоть из другой актвиити. Надо только с `lanchMode` поиграться. С комбинированием `action` и `category`, вроде, не должно быть проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подведу итог. Решил, но по другому. Я создал класс Observable добавил модель в observer, а из activity (не основной) я вызывал метод Observable, в который передавал данные, а в нем уже оповещал notifyObservers(Text). Так все прекрасно работает. Спасибо за помощь.